# Type error: 'module' object has no attribute '_getitem_'

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch emails and then we need to write the mails in to different files according to the subject.

```
import email
import imaplib
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import time

def myThreadFun():

    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    M.login("noticeboard16@gmail.com", "embeddedSystems")



    while (1):

        M.select()

        rv, data1 = M.search(None, 'UNSEEN')

        for i in data1[0].split():

            resp, data = M.FETCH(i, '(RFC822)')
            mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

            for part in mail.walk():

                # multipart are just containers, so we skip them
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                    continue

                # we are interested only in the simple text messages
                if part.get_content_subtype() != 'plain':
                    continue



                payload = part.get_payload()
                print '\n' 
                print '[%s]' % (mail['Subject']) 
                print 'From:  %s' % (mail['From']) 
                print 'Date:', mail['Date']
                print '=================================' 
                print payload
                #time.sleep(10)

                #save_string = str("/home/buddhi-xubuntu/Python/email_" + ".text")
                #myfile = open(save_string, 'a')
                #myfile.write(mail['Subject']+ "\nFrom: " +  mail['From'] + "\nDate: " + mail['Date'] + "=============\n" + payload)
                #myfile.close()
                #time.sleep(10)


                #with file('email_.txt', 'r') as original: data = original.read()
                #with file('email_2.txt', 'w') as modified: modified.write(mail['Subject']+ "\nFrom: " +  mail['From'] + "\nDate: " + mail['Date'] + "\n=============\n" + payload + "\n" + data)

                #orig_string = str("/home/e11452/Downloads/email_" + ".text")
                #f = open(orig_string,'r')
                #temp = f.read()
                #f.close()


                if mail['Subject']=="E/11":
                    new_string = str("/home/e11452/Downloads/email_11" + ".text")
                    f = open(new_string, 'w')
                    f.write(mail['Subject']+ "\nFrom: " +  mail['From'] + "\nDate: " + mail['Date'] + "\n=============\n" + payload + "\n")

                elif mail['Subject']=="E/10":
                    new_string = str("/home/e11452/Downloads/email_12" + ".text")
                    -f = open(new_string, 'w')
                    f.write(mail['Subject']+ "\nFrom: " +  mail['From'] + "\nDate: " + mail['Date'] + "\n=============\n" + payload + "\n")


                f.write(temp)
                f.close()


                time.sleep(10)

    M.LOGOUT()

thread = Thread(target = myThreadFun)

thread.start()
```

above is the code i tried and i get an error saying

Traceback (most recent call last): File "email14.py", line 58, in  if email['Subject'] == 'E/11': TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't match the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you misspell `mail` as `email`. `email` is a module you imported. Then you got the error.

Comment: I saw `if mail['Subject']=="E/11":`, but the error suggested that it's `if email['Subject'] == 'E/11':`. So I'm guessing the code above is inaccurate.